# Работа While True и sqlite3

Tags: python

Привет всем,
Как я могу вынести INSERT INTO за приделы функции enter(), но что бы While True продолжал работать, пока я не остановлю цикл, он должен продолжать посылать данные. Код работает, но я уверен что он написан не правильно.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')  
c = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table('
          ' first_name TEXT NOT NULL,'
          ' second_name TEXT NOT NULL,'
          ' date TEXT NOT NULL)')

date = raw_input("Enter date: ")


def enter():
   while True:

    f = raw_input("Enter name: ")
    e = raw_input("Enter second name: ")

    if len(f) == 0:
        break
    elif len(e) == 0:
        break
    else:

        def first_name():
            a = f
            return a

        def second_name():
            y = e
            return y

        f_name = first_name()
        s_name  = second_name()

        c.execute("INSERT INTO test_table(first_name, "
                  "second_name, date)VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
                  (f_name, s_name, date))

        conn.commit() 


create_table()
enter()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

сделайте глобальную переменную и в нее сохраняйте введеные данные. После вызова функции 'enter' сохрание в таблицу данные если они существуют.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')  
c = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute(' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table('
          ' first_name TEXT NOT NULL,'
          ' second_name TEXT NOT NULL,'
          ' date TEXT NOT NULL)')

date = raw_input("Enter date: ")

data = []

def enter():

    global data

    while True:

        f = raw_input("Enter name: ")
        e = raw_input("Enter second name: ")

        if len(f) == 0:
            break
        elif len(e) == 0:
            break
        else:

            def first_name():
                a = f
                return a

            def second_name():
                y = e
                return y

            f_name = first_name()
            s_name  = second_name()

            data.append((f_name, s_name, date))

create_table()

enter()

if data:
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO test_table(first_name, "
              "second_name, date)VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
              data)
    conn.commit() 

conn.close()
```